# Pass parameter and use custom attributes?

Tags: html, parameters, salesforce, apex-code

I have the following code in my view:

```
<apex:commandLink data-role="button" action="{!someAction}">
<apex:param name="someVar" value="someVarVal">
</apex:commandLink>
```

The code does not work because commandLink does not take the "data-role" attribute.

How can I pass a parameter like I am with the second line, but also have an attribute like "data-role" on the rendered link?

Answer (score 2):

I've never found a way to put extra attributes into VF tags, your best bet IMO would be to add some javascript which runs on page load and then use JQuery's `.attr()` method to add the attribute to the component.

Something like the following (assuming you've [included jquery through a static resource](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm))

```
<apex:commandLink styleClass="myLink" action="{!someAction}">
    <apex:param name="someVar" value="someVarVal"/>
</apex:commandLink>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".myLink").attr("data-role", "button");
    });
<script>
```

You'll notice I've used a class instead of ID here, this is simply because SFDC generated IDs include symbols which need to be escaped for use with jQuery, and I find this is just the easier and cleaner solution to use (albeit probably slightly slower).

Comment: Pretty sure class="myLink" should be styleClass="myLink". Otherwise, this is pretty much the solution I use for this type of problem as well. +1.

Comment: Absolutely right, have modified it. Always screw something up when I type in code samples on the fly!

Answer (score 0):

you can just use html pass through syntax :

```
html-attribute=value
```

for example

```
html-class="toto" will output class="toto"
```